# Why does tomcat's Bytes received under Server Status always report 0.00 MB?

Tags: tomcat, monitoring

When I access the Manager application for the http-8080 connector under Server Status I always get 0.00 MB under the Bytes received field even though the Bytes sent field is populated.

Anyone know why? This is on 6.0.30.

Bug?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

It's known as bug [46991](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46991), and according to [Changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/changelog.html) it is already fixed from version 6.0.20. Did you try to submit some data to see if `Bytes received` change to non-zero.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not using the JK module and this is in 6.0.30